# free certificate that EC2 allows using for SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any free CA that I can use for using SSL in an EC2 web-site that issues free certificates?

If I read EC2 documentation correctly - the certificate that is being used has to be verifiable, which with Verisign (etc.) costs money, and I really want to keep it free.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears one can use openssl to create for themselves certificates for EC2, 
and therefore it does not have to be sign by an external entity.

I created one, and posted it using this manual:
http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Although the browser does not like it, I don't need the user browser to approve it since I need it just for encryption in a web service...

Answer (score 0):

This question is off-topic but yes you can use Startcom. It's a free certificate authority for first level verification certificates.

http://cert.startcom.org/

If you want an extended verification certificate, so that when somebody browses on your site it shows the "green bar" then you will have to pay. (Startcom charges for this too, others will also charge of course)

Other like [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/landing/ssl-certificate/free-ssl/?gclid=CLPO2OXwxL0CFW1nOgodZH0AFA) will also provide you with free certificate but that's good only for 90 days.

Comment: Do you know which I need to be able to upload a certificate to the AWS (I think it's the load balancer that I upload it to)? I don't care about user browsing since I wrote a WS that my app is contacting, I just want the content to be encrypted by SSL out of the box..